# CanCan and InheritedResources: load and authorize resource through a singleton resource without ID param in the URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, singleton, cancan, nested-routes, inherited-resources

My users can define their own vocabularies.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :vocabularies
end

class Vocabulary < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Routes:

```
resource :user do
  resources :vocabularies
end
```

Now I want to use CanCan to load and authorize the vocabulary resource through the loaded user resource in the `CategoriesController`, but I'm pretty unsure how to configure CanCan correctly.

One thing is that I don't pass the user's ID through the URL params, so I have to tell CanCan somehow manually how to load the user. My guess is that I can simply do a `through: :current_user`. And because it is a singleton resource, I think I will have to pass the `singleton: true` option:

```
class VocabulariesController < ApplicationController
  inherit_resources
  belongs_to :current_user # Is this correct?
  load_and_authorize_resource through: :current_user, singleton: true
end
```

But when trying to access `user/vocabularies`, I'm getting a `Couldn't find Vocabulary without an ID` error. And `user/vocabularies/new` results in `undefined method`current_user=' for #`. No idea where's the problem, is it CanCan? InheritedResources? Misconfig?

Comment: Personally I'd ditch CanCan.  Have used it and other gems in the past but these days find it far simpler to code up a simple permissions class.

Comment: I find it very convenient, and the CanCanCan project has taken care of maintaining the gem while Ryan Bates cures from burn out.